# react native onesignal unable to register users in android

Tags: android, react-native, onesignal

After following the setup, android users are still not registering on my Onesignal dashboard.

I've modified both my **android/app/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {


repositories {
      maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal
  }
  dependencies {
      classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.1, 0.99.99]'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
```

as well as adding the code below to my **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
  android:launchMode="singleTop"...
```

and initializing it on app launch following the code in the documentation which I know to be correct since it works well on iOS.

Looking for help on this. Thank you.

Comment: Are you testing it on the real device? Could you give me some more information? If you are trying in emulator; Cloud Messaging, such as Push Notification, sometimes works and sometimes does not work when trying on the emulator. If I'm using firebase, I have a lot of questions about it on stackoverflow.

Comment: I've tested it both an emulator and on a real android device: Motorola E4

Comment: I understand you get this error when you integrate it into your own project. Can you try running the instance in the OneSignal repo (examples folder)? So let's see if the problem is from you or onesignal.

Comment: Works well on iOS doesn't mean that you have done everything correctly on Android. I've faced this situation too and as a suggestion I'd like you to tell, just go through the documentation again.

Comment: Been through the documentation multiple times for hours already but thank you.

Comment: I can't figure out how to make the exemple project work. Do you have one?

Comment: Simply clone this repo (https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal/tree/master/examples/RNOneSignal). Then *npm install*. Change one signal key in **App.js**. And run. I am waiting your response:)

Comment: Ok I just tried and it works, it does register my devices.

Comment: I've tried copying every single piece of code to my project but still wont register my devices when using my initial project.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the Troubleshooting page? https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/troubleshooting-react-native